# Is USB OTG disabled on my device?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, usb-on-the-go, alcatel-one-touch-idol-s

In using my Alcatel one touch idol s (4.2.2) I noticed that although USB OTG should be on my device, it isn't. Did they disable or remove it?